# Salesforce EventLogs for Field & Validation changes

Tags: validation, fields

does anybody know if salesforce eventlogs picks up logs for whenever a user adds and new field or makes changes to a field on application? Would this show in transaction logs?

Here's an example:
Bob creates a new input field for his salesforce app, later on he decides to change that field, or even change how the validation on this field works. Will SalesForce event logs capture these activities in a audit log somewhere?

Comment: Why not just use `Setup Audit Trail`?

Answer (score 1):

In your case assuming Bob is an admin, you can use [Monitor Setup Changes](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_monitorsetup.htm&type=5) to track these type of activities in your Org. These type of activities are tracked in the Audit Trail.

> Setup Audit Trail tracks the recent setup changes that you and other admins have made to your org. Audit history is especially useful in orgs with multiple admins.

You can take a look at the documentation for more details as what you can track vs. not.